# In atom text editor, I'm not able to use jinja, it is not taking or reading the variable name

Tags: jinja2

here are the image of the code which i was working on .
[this the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlA96.png)

[this is the code which I was working on .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/681vT.png)

Comment: did you install the plugin ? https://atom.io/packages/atom-jinja2

Comment: yes, I have installed atom-jinja2 package.